# Excel conditional formating - conditional on sum of all previous cells and total sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a question with regards to conditional formatting which I simply can't seem to solve.

The aim is to format the background color for the left-most cells that are blank up until a cell contains a value - and after this there should be no more formatting in this row. You can see an image of the result I'm hoping for beneath:

[image]

So far I've managed to create the conditional formatting of the blank rows, but sadly haven't managed to create the "single-cell" formatting (in yellow) conditional of the sum of all the first cells being `= 0`.

I've created a formula which actually succeeds in calculating the sum of the previous cells, but this formula includes `INDIRECT()` which it seems that conditional formatting doesn't allow. At least I'm getting an error starting with the follow (translating the error from Danish to English might not be intuitive):

> You cannot use reference operators such as.....

The formula I'm trying is the following:

`=AND(SUM(A2:INDIRECT(IF(COLUMN(A2)>=27;CHAR((64-26)+COLUMN(A2))&CHAR((64-26)+COLUMN(A2))&ROW(A2);CHAR((64)+COLUMN(A2))&ROW(A2))))>0;$K2>0)`

Where `$K2` is the sum of the row.

Is there a way to SUM a range of cells by doing something similar to this:
`=SUM(B2:CHAR((64)+COLUMN())&ROW();""))` to dynamically SUM the range from B2 to the current cell? The problem in this case is whether the part `CHAR((64)+COLUMN())&ROW();"")` can be converted into a legible cell such as `B4` to make it work inside the `=SUM()` formula?

Sadly the `=ADDRESS()` formula cannot be used (as far as I know) as this will trigger the same error in conditional formatting as well.

For now I would like this to work with the regular Excel conditional formatting, but if anyone have a simple VBA this would also have interest - however, I would *by far* prefer the regular solution.

The question:
Is there a way to create a formula that doesn't trigger this error - maybe by refrasing the formula or doing something completely else?

Comment: Why isn't F4 yellow?

Comment: That is by intention. It's to show visually, to which point in the row that nothing has occurred and at which point (in which column) the first occurrences happen. In row 4 the first data-point occurs in column D, and therefore the formatting should stop after this point in the current row. I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this could be handled with a much simpler CFR formula like,

```
=and(not(sum($a2:a2)), $k2)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the K2<>0 reference even necessary? If there are any numbers in A2:I2 then K2 will not 0 unless pos/neg pairs are a possibility.

Comment: You are (almost) entirely correct! The only thing missing was setting the sum `= 0` and then it works perfect. I can't believe that I exaggerated this issue by that much - thank you! 
Maybe you would edit your answer to reflect the formula with `= 0` which thereby matches the blank cells and making the background of these format properly? The formula I've used successfully is:
`=AND(SUM($A2:A2)=0, $K2)`

Comment: Yes, zero is considered false on a worksheet and anything that is not false is true. I should have used `not(sum($a2:a2))` inside the AND. Thanks for catching that; corrected above.